# Pandas - drop last column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I would like to drop the last column of it. Until now I had just been dropping what I believed to be the final column with

`if len(fish_frame.columns) == 4:
    del fish_frame[3]`.

Right before this command, however, I drop all columns of `NaN`s. So that removes column `[3]` because it is filled with `NaN`s, so it fails.

I would like to say just drop the final column of the entire DataFrame. I feel like that would work perfectly.

I tried `fish_frame([:-1], axis=1)` but that's invalid syntax.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

The DataFrame:

```
fish_frame after dropna:

                              0        1      2           4
0                         #0721      NaN    NaN         NaN
1                       GBE COD      746  $2.00   $1,492.00
2                       GBW COD   13,894  $0.50   $6,947.00
3                       GOM COD       60  $2.00     $120.00
4            GB WINTER FLOUNDER   94,158  $0.25  $23,539.50
5           GOM WINTER FLOUNDER    3,030  $0.50   $1,515.00
6                   GBE HADDOCK   18,479  $0.02     $369.58
7                   GOM HADDOCK        0  $0.02       $0.00
8                   GBW HADDOCK  110,470  $0.02   $2,209.40
9                          HAKE      259  $1.30     $336.70
10                       PLAICE    3,738  $0.40   $1,495.20
11                      POLLOCK    3,265  $0.02      $65.30
12               WITCH FLOUNDER    1,134  $1.30   $1,474.20
13                       SNE YT    1,458  $0.65     $947.70
14                        GB YT    4,499  $0.70   $3,149.30
15                      REDFISH      841  $0.02      $16.82
16  54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00      NaN    NaN        None
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `iloc` and list indexing

```
fish_frame = fish_frame.iloc[:, :-1]

                              0        1      2
0                         #0721      NaN    NaN
1                       GBE COD      746  $2.00
2                       GBW COD   13,894  $0.50
3                       GOM COD       60  $2.00
4            GB WINTER FLOUNDER   94,158  $0.25
5           GOM WINTER FLOUNDER    3,030  $0.50
6                   GBE HADDOCK   18,479  $0.02
7                   GOM HADDOCK        0  $0.02
8                   GBW HADDOCK  110,470  $0.02
9                          HAKE      259  $1.30
10                       PLAICE    3,738  $0.40
11                      POLLOCK    3,265  $0.02
12               WITCH FLOUNDER    1,134  $1.30
13                       SNE YT    1,458  $0.65
14                        GB YT    4,499  $0.70
15                      REDFISH      841  $0.02
16  54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00      NaN    NaN
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change mine at all. Does that mean there are more columns in my dataframe that I can't see or?

Comment: Ok gotcha. That worked perfectly thanks a lot. Just so I understand: is `iloc` the all around best method to use when indexing? I've seen it around a lot

Comment: `iloc` is the idiomatic approach for handling positional requirements.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to drop the last column

```
df = df.iloc[:,:-1]
```

if particular column needs to be dropped with index

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[column_index],axis=1)
```

with column name

```
df = df.drop(['column_name'],axis =1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use drop with the columns index:

```
fish_frame = fish_frame.drop(fish_frame.columns[-1],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                              0        1      2
0                         #0721      NaN    NaN
1                       GBE COD      746  $2.00
2                       GBW COD   13,894  $0.50
3                       GOM COD       60  $2.00
4            GB WINTER FLOUNDER   94,158  $0.25
5           GOM WINTER FLOUNDER    3,030  $0.50
6                   GBE HADDOCK   18,479  $0.02
7                   GOM HADDOCK        0  $0.02
8                   GBW HADDOCK  110,470  $0.02
9                          HAKE      259  $1.30
10                       PLAICE    3,738  $0.40
11                      POLLOCK    3,265  $0.02
12               WITCH FLOUNDER    1,134  $1.30
13                       SNE YT    1,458  $0.65
14                        GB YT    4,499  $0.70
15                      REDFISH      841  $0.02
16  54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00      NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This will most likely work with OP's dataframe.  However, in the general sense, if that last column name is repeated anywhere else in the dataframe, it will drop those columns as well. Plus One :-)

Comment: Oh.. yes.  if there are duplicate column it will drop all occurrences of that column name.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to drop the last column

`df = df[df.columns[:-1]]`

Answer (score 0):

`fish_frame.drop(fish_frame.columns[len(fish_frame.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)`